# Combining multiple Prometheus queries in a Grafana dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have metrics that represent k8s cluster versions based on semver and generate the following:

```
cluster_major_version{Name="cluster-1"} 1
cluster_major_version{Name="cluster-2"} 1

cluster_minor_version{Name="cluster-1"} 22
cluster_minor_version{Name="cluster-2"} 24

cluster_patch_version{Name="cluster-1"} 13
cluster_patch_version{Name="cluster-2"} 4
```

In a Grafana dashboard I can extract `major`, `minor` and `patch` from three separate queries and put them in a table which has the headings:

`Cluster | Major | Minor | Patch`

However I wish to combine these values so instead of having each metric in a separate column, I have something like

`Cluster | Version`

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grafana transformation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/panels/transform-data/transformation-functions/).

[Concatenate](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/panels/transform-data/transformation-functions/#concatenate-fields) should do the job